# Jasmine wait till function called by listener gets executed

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, jasmine

So I have this function which is called when some backbone model attribute is set. I.e:

```
this.listenTo(model, "change:someattr", changeCallback);
```

What I want to do in my Jasmine tests is to set this attribute and then check if `changeCallback` got called successfully and if it resulted in desired changes. In my code below it looks like my `changeCallback` function gets called after jasmine assertions are executed.

```
that.model.set('someattr', 'xyz');
expect(that.model.changeCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Any ideas how to test this? All code examples I've found deal with asych calls which are executed directly on asynchronous function.

Comment: Can you clarify where the changeCallback lives? On your first code exactly, it seems like it lives on a view, but the second it seems like the callback is on the model itself?

Answer (score 0):

The model change callback will happen immediately as there is no server response to wait for so just:

1. Spy on changeCallback and call through (http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies:_`and.callThrough`).
2. model.set("attributeToChange", "somethingNew")
3. Assert that the changeCallback spy was called
4. Assert that the expected behavior occurred.

Alternatively, you could split into two tests where one just tests that changing the attribute triggered the callback and a second which just tested the callback function itself.